# AForge, memory stacking up

Tags: c#, memory, aforge

Im trying to grab a frame with C# and AForge libraries:

```
...
using AForge.Video
using AForge.Video.DirectShow

namespace Example
{
     class Program
     {

      private static Bitmap mySnap = null;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
             snapByte();
      }

      private static void snapByte()
      {
                    int Counter = 0;
                    FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
                    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(videoNewFrame);
                    videoSource.Start();
                    do
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        Counter++;
                    }
                    while (mySnap == null && Counter < 4);
                    if (videoSource.IsRunning)
                    {
                        videoSource.SignalToStop();
                        videoSource.WaitForStop();
                        videoSource = null;
                    }
                    MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream();
                    mySnap.Save(myStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] snapByteLength = MyStream.ToArray();
                    int snapLength = snapByteLength.Length;
                    Console.WriteLine(snapLength);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    myStream.Dispose();
                    mySnap = null;
                    snapByte();
            }
        }

        private static void videoNewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
             mySnap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
   }
}
```

this is the exact code im using, i just changed the image byte processing to display the byte length to simplify things..

the problem im having is that the memory will keep staking up anywhere between 1-2 mb each time a snapshot is taken..
i am disposing of all my bitmaps except for the mySnap that im returning to null.. i cant dispose of mySnap because its used again, and i have to declare it global because i use this in snapByte() and newVideoFrame() 
but since im reusing mySnap i dont see why would it be stacking up.. it should be overwriting everytime..

i have seen other answers but all have to do with a picturebox, and the answer is to clear the picturebox before loading a new image..
i believe im doing the equivalent here by calling mySnap=null again..
but memory still stacking up...

Thank You..

Comment: no one?? im guessing this should be a memory leak within AForge's libraries then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an infinite recursion by your unconditional call to `snapByte()` at the end of the `snapByte()` method.  **This creates a loop that will eventually crash once your stack runs out of space**; every time your method calls itself, you are setting up a new stack frame that will never be cleared because the method never returns.  This may take a while to manifest because of the `Thread.Sleep()` call that will keep your recursive calls throttled.

**Also, any reference that was not nulled before you recursively call snapByte() will be held indefinitely in memory, since those references are alive in a scope that will never exit (because of the infinite recursion) and will never be reclaimed by the GC.**

This is the case for your `videoDevices` collection but more importantly for the `snapByteLength` array instance, that is holding a copy of the bitmap you just captured.  I bet this is the primary cause for your memory leak

**Avoiding recursion and converting it to a simple loop should fix your issues.**

Comment: Thank you very much.. now i see it!
will implement a loop instead, thank you.

Comment: De nada Joel, da gusto encontrar por aquí gente de México  =)